# Access VNC server running in Android from Ubuntu

Tags: networking, android, vnc, vncviewer

I am running ubuntu in an android phone and I have the address of its vnc server. Is it possible to access the vncserver from another computer in the same network?

I connected the laptop to the mobile phone's Ethernet hotspot and tried to connect to `localhost:1` (which works with the mobile phone's vnc viewer) in Real VNC but it said that the remote computer refused to connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the phone settings --> about. Find the IP address.

Then, in VNC viewer, connect to `IP:address:5901` (5901 stands for `localhost:1`)